# Where to put gradiant background lines for all screens (read only in 1 place: without having redundant code)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I read somewhere that main.dart shall be a very minimal file focused on routes in the MaterialApp Widget.

The background  of the app is not a single color (therefore can't set in a theme for all screens) and I have to use this in order to achieve the gradiant background:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    // gradient background
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [colorBackground1, colorBackground2]),
    ),
    child: SafeArea(
```

Question is, where do I put these lines of code (that I wrote above) if I don't want to have redundant code at the beginning of every screen Widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to set the gradient background color from one place, so there is no redundant code but it looks like this is the best solution.

1.Create a file gradient_background_wrapper.dart in [project]/theme/ folder:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientBackgroundWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  GradientBackgroundWrapper({this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      // gradient background
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter, colors: [colorBackground1, colorBackground2]),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

2.And then for every screen that uses the gradient background just use it as the first parent widget like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../theme/gradient_background_wrapper.dart';

class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GradientBackgroundWrapper(
      child: Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```